# Find related facebook interests using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out a way find related interests on Facebook. E.g. I want to search for Cityville and result should be Farmville, Castleville etc.

Is there an API to support this, what are the alternatives?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's not an endpoint to achieve what you want. You can inspect a users interests in the graph api, but then it would be up to you to create an algorithm that decides what's related, most likely by inspecting a large number of peoples interests and comparing. Of course they would all have to authorize your application though. Alternatively you could try and do something inspecting the application table and comparing descriptions, category and subcategory https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application

Answer (score 0):

You can search the JSON result by the **Graph API** with the url https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=**{your_token_here}**, replacing the "me" with the Facebook User ID/Name.

If you are looking for pages search, you can use the same API, with the url https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=**{keyword}**&type=page&access_token=**{your_token_here}**.